# "Invalid initialization" error when reading from a map

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following error when trying to build:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type "std::vector<......"
```

Code:

```
class Config {
    public:
        std::vector<string>& GetValuesForList(std::string listName);

    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::vector<string> > lists;
    };

    inline std::vector<string>&
    Config::GetValuesForList(std::string listName) {
        return lists.find(listName);
    }
```

I've read up on it and seems to be because of C++ temporaries, but am unsure how to resolve it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) returns iterator. So you should use it's second value:

```
    inline std::vector<string>&
    Config::GetValuesForList(std::string listName) {
        return lists.find(listName)->second;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want `return lists.find(listName)->second;`?

[Side note: `lists` is not a very good name for a thing that is a `map` of `vector`!]

Answer (score 0):

`map::find()` returns an iterator to `pair<key,value>`.

I think its better to write this:

```
std::vector<string>& Config::GetValuesForList(std::string listName) 
{
    return lists[listName];
}
```

If the key `listName` exists in the map, then it will return the associated value. Otherwise, it will create a new entry in the map, and will return the newly created `std::vector<T>` which would be empty.

I would also like to suggest you to add another function as `bool DoesExist(std::string listName)` which you may use to inspect, before calling the above function so as to avoid creating new entry if the key is not found:

```
bool DoesExist(std::string listName)
{
   return lists.find(listName) != lists.end();
}
```

Also, it would be better if you change the name `lists` to `vecMap` .

Comment: This will create the element if the key cannot be found, though.

Comment: @Oli: Yes. I was adding this info, in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map<T>::find()` returns a `std::map<T>::iterator`, not reference to the value type.  What you want is the below

```
  inline std::vector<string>&
    Config::GetValuesForList(std::string listName) {
         std::map<std::string, std::vector<string> >::iterator  itr = lists.find(listName);
         if (itr != lists.end()) {
             return itr->second;;
         } else {
           // What to do if not found.
         }
    }
```

As a note, if you want it to create a new empty vector if not found, then you can simplify the whole thing to

```
  inline std::vector<string>&
    Config::GetValuesForList(std::string listName) {
         return lists[listName]; // Creates a new vector if listname not found
    }
```